# how to optimize this Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, optimization, profiling, collatz

I use the following code to memoize the total stopping time of [Collatz function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) by using a state monad to cache input-result pairs.

Additionally the `snd` part of the state is used to keep track of the input value that maximizes the output, and the goal is to find the input value under one million that maximuzes the total stopping time. (The problem can be found on [project euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14).

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Monad.State
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

collatz :: Integer -> Integer
collatz n = if odd n
              then 3 * n + 1
              else n `div` 2

memoCollatz :: Integer
            -> State (M.Map Integer Int, (Integer,Int)) Int
memoCollatz 1 = return 1
memoCollatz n = do
    result <- gets (M.lookup n . fst)
    case result of
        Nothing -> do
            l <- succ <$> memoCollatz (collatz n)
            let update p@(_,curMaxV) =
                    if l > curMaxV
                       then (n,l)
                       else p
            modify (M.insert n l *** update)
            return l
        Just v -> return v

main :: IO ()
main = print $ snd (execState (mapM_ memoCollatz [1..limit]) (M.empty,(1,1)))
  where
    limit = 1000000
```

The program works fine but is really slow. So I want to spend some time figuring out
how to make it work faster.

I took a look at the profiling chapter of [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html), but have no clue about what is the problem:

I compiled it using `ghc -O2 -rtsopts -prof -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp`, and ran it with `+RTS -s -p` and here is the result:

```
   6,633,397,720 bytes allocated in the heap
   9,357,527,000 bytes copied during GC
   2,616,881,120 bytes maximum residency (15 sample(s))
      60,183,944 bytes maximum slop
            5274 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     10570 colls,     0 par    3.36s    3.36s     0.0003s    0.0013s
  Gen  1        15 colls,     0 par    7.03s    7.03s     0.4683s    3.4337s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    4.02s  (  4.01s elapsed)
  GC      time   10.39s  ( 10.39s elapsed)
  RP      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  PROF    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.16s  (  0.16s elapsed)
  Total   time   14.57s  ( 14.56s elapsed)

  %GC     time      71.3%  (71.3% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    1,651,363,842 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  28.7% of total user, 28.7% of total elapsed
```

And the `.prof` file:

```
    total time  =        4.08 secs   (4080 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 3,567,324,056 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE        MODULE    %time %alloc

memoCollatz        Main       84.9   91.9
memoCollatz.update Main       10.5    0.0
main               Main        2.4    5.8
collatz            Main        2.2    2.3


                                                                 individual     inherited
COST CENTRE            MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN                   MAIN                     52           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main                  Main                    105           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main1             Main                    102           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                 Main                    104           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main2             Main                    101           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                 Main                    106           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main4             Main                    100           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main                 Main                    107           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF:main5             Main                     99           0    0.0    0.0    94.4   86.7
  main                 Main                    108           0    1.4    0.9    94.4   86.7
   memoCollatz         Main                    113           0   82.4   85.8    92.9   85.8
    memoCollatz.update Main                    115     2168610   10.5    0.0    10.5    0.0
 CAF:main10            Main                     98           0    0.0    0.0     5.1   11.0
  main                 Main                    109           0    0.4    2.7     5.1   11.0
   memoCollatz         Main                    112     3168610    2.5    6.0     4.7    8.3
    collatz            Main                    114     2168610    2.2    2.3     2.2    2.3
 CAF:main11            Main                     97           0    0.0    0.0     0.5    2.2
  main                 Main                    110           0    0.5    2.2     0.5    2.2
   main.limit          Main                    111           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                   GHC.Conc.Signal          94           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                   GHC.IO.Encoding          89           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                   GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv    88           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF                   GHC.IO.Handle.FD         82           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

What I can see is that the garbage collector is taking too much time and the program has spent most of its time running `memoCollatz`.

And here are two screenshots from heap profiling:

[image: Imgur1]

[image: Imgur2]

I expect the memory usage to increase and then decrease rapidly because the program is doing memoization using a Map, but not sure what is causing the rapid drop in the graph (maybe this is a bug when visualizing the result?).

I want to know how to analyze these tables / graphs and how they indicates the real problem.

Comment: Any way you look at it, the line that says `2,616,881,120 bytes maximum residency (15 sample(s))` looks like bad news.

Comment: Is this about Euler#14? In this case, this question _might_ be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416292/project-euler-14-tips-in-haskell/22417267#22417267, although user5402's solution is faster.

Comment: this is *not* about PE#14. I'm not interested in what the answer is, I want to know what you can draw from these profiling data and how you might take action accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The Haskell Wiki contains a couple of different solutions to this problem: [(link)](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems/11_to_20)

The fastest solution there uses an Array to memoize the results. On my machine it runs in about 1 second and max. residency is about 35 MB.

Below is a version which runs in about 0.3 seconds and uses 1/4 of the memory of the Array version but it runs in the IO monad.

There are trade-offs between all of the different versions, and you have to decide which one you consider acceptable.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.Array.IO
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Control.Monad

collatz x
  | even x    = div x 2
  | otherwise = 3*x+1

solve n = do
  arr <- newArray (1,n) 0 :: IO (IOUArray Int Int)
  writeArray arr 1 1
  let eval :: Int -> IO Int
      eval x = do
        if x > n
          then fmap (1+) $ eval (collatz x)
          else do d <- readArray arr x
                  if d == 0
                    then do d <- fmap (1+) $ eval (collatz x)
                            writeArray arr x d
                            return d
                    else return d
      go :: (Int,Int) -> Int -> IO (Int,Int)
      go !m x = do d <- eval x
                   return $ max m (d,x)
  foldM go (0,0) [2..n]

main = solve 1000000 >>= print
```

Comment: Why would you use `IO` instead of `ST` for this?

Comment: No reason - I expect the performance to be the same under ST. Developing and debugging using the IO monad is easier though.