# Questions regarding Haskell solution of Project Euler 14

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, memoization

This is the [Question 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14).

```
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import Data.Ord (comparing)

syrs n = a
  where 

    -- For those who don't want to lookup array in the reference
    -- the following line creates an array indexed from 1 to n 
    -- using the list provided. And a ! x is the syntax for a[x] in some other languages.

    a = listArray (1,n) $ 0 : [1 + syr n x | x <- [2..n]]   -------- 2
    syr n x = if x' <= n                                    -------- 1
            then a ! x'                                     -------- 1
            else 1 + syr n x'                               
      where 
        x' = if even x
             then x `div` 2
             else 3 * x + 1

main = print $ maximumBy (comparing snd) $ assocs $ syrs 1000000
```

Above is the suggested solution for [Project Euler Q14 on wiki.haskell.org](https://wiki.haskell.org/Euler_problems/11_to_20#Problem_14). The algorithm is largely the same to mine (but mine runs forever while this runs in 2sec).

Question:

In line 2, it calls `syr n x`. Suppose `x = 3`, `x' = 10`, `10 < n`, it will proceed with `then` clause : `a ! 10`. But at this time, `a ! 10` is not yet calculated. How does the program proceed then?

---

Comment: Do ya wanna sort out that formatting? I don't think many people can read it...

Comment: @AJFarmar How should I sort out the formatting? Questions before code?

Comment: If it were valid haskell code, that'd be nice, but I think I could do it for you now. I'll edit for a moment.

Comment: I guess he is talking about the indentation. But I would also simplify the code and drop "a": I would say `syrs n = listArray (1,n) ...`

Comment: Please post your own broken code in full. It's very hard to do mental multiple search/replace while reading code.

Comment: #14? That sounds... familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416292/project-euler-14-tips-in-haskell. That being said, if you have _working_ code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com could be a better place.

Comment: @AJFarmar Your edit changed the formatting from what was on the Haskell wiki. It's no longer a real quote.

Comment: @Michael Actually that is my question 1. It turns out that adding `a` boosts performance in a way that I don't know.

Comment: @pspencil - you should compile with `-O2` if you want to measure anything. 1) compiling with `-O2` has a bigger performance impact that wether you inline `a` or not. 2) If you compile with `-O2` I'm sure that it will not have any performance impact wether you inline `a` or not. 3) I'm still a Haskell beginner, so I cannot just answer all your questions...

Comment: @Michael I tried to compile with `ghc -O2 -o TEST TEST.hs`. I deleted a and changed `a ! x'` to `(syrs n) ! x'` (if this is what you mean). Before change, it finishes in 1 second. After, however, it did not finish in 1 minute, which I don't know why.

Comment: By the way, when you say "mine runs forever", do you mean that it runs a long time, or that there's an infinite loop and it never terminates?

Comment: @JustinL. As my point 2 points out, I think there is an infinite loop. Bit by bit, I modified my code to look like what was given as the answer and at certain point, when those differ by the difference in point 2, there is an infinite loop error. (previously, there is no notification)

Comment: ... and you still haven't included your code in the question. it is impossible to answer then. voting to close. SO is not your personal service (no offense intended), the Q&A entries must make sense on their own, to a casual reader 10 years from now. (to your question above, if you replace `a ! ...` with `(syrs n) ! ...`, you destroy memoization and cause recalculation, i.e. computation explosion. `a` stores the previously calculated result, without it there is no memoization.

Comment: your `syr` must be able to refer to _the same_ array when processing different arguments, so the results are stored in that array, and not recalculated; to be able to refer to the _same_ array you must _name_ it and refer to it by its name. ["if you name it, it will stay"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11466959/849891).

Comment: @WillNess Thank you for your answer. As my program only differed from the given answer by tiny little details, I thought it would be better to point out those details than to leave it for you to spot the difference, not to mention the pain in corresponding variable names. Anyway, now, question 1 & 2 have already been solved and question 3 does not require my code so it doesn't matter now. I have re-edited the question. Is that clear enough now? (I want to keep the older questions as reference, but failed to find a strikethrough format).

Comment: I've edited to remove all the irrelevant, draft stuff, to make the question specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell98 Report [states](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/array.html), *" `array` is strict in the bounds argument and in the indices of the association list, but nonstrict in the values"*. `listArray` is similar.

What this means is that the *structure* of an array is created right away – i.e. the *n* *"cells"* that are to hold the values – but the *values* themselves are lazy, as is usual in Haskell.

Your function's definition, simplified, is

```
import Data.Array
import Data.List
import Data.Ord (comparing)

syrs n = 
    a
    where 
    a = listArray (1,n) $ 0 : map syr [2..n]
    syr x = 
        if y <= n then 1 + a ! y else 1 + syr y
        where 
        y = if even x then x `div` 2 else 3 * x + 1
```

With it,

```
a ! i === (0 : map syr [2..n]) !! (i-1) , i = 1..n
      === if i==1 then 0
                  else (map syr [2..n]) !! (i-2) , i = 2..n
      === if i==1 then 0
                  else syr i
```

When the value `a ! 10` is *needed*, it is calculated according to the above definition, and then stored under the index `10` in the array `a`. Calculating it will proceed in the usual fashion, viz. `a ! 5` will be demanded, triggering *its* calculation, and conditionally storing the result in the array.

So, in pseudocode,

```
syr x = a ! x     , if already calculated and stored in the array
      = 1 + syr y , storing the result in the array under x, if x <= n
      = 1 + syr y , otherwise
  where
  y = ....
```

The usual, recursive, lazy evaluation of Haskell.